# How to print the next line after condition satisfied using shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, sed

I have data files in following format.

```
file.dat
the value of abc is
56
the value of xyz is
60
the value of pqr is
54
the value of xyz is
78
.......
```

My output will be

```
file.dat
56
60
54
78
```

I am using the following method, but it does not look me proper.

```
sed -i 's/^the/d' file.dat
sed -i 's/^$/d' file.dat
```

Is there any other good way to do it?

I also want to print only the xyz values. like: if the line contains xyz then print the next line.

```
file.dat 
60
78
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say

```
sed -n '/the value of xyz/ { n; p; }' file.dat
```

This works as follows: `-n` disables auto-printing (so that `n` doesn't print anything), and the code is

```
/the value of xyz/ {   # if a line contains "the value of xyz"
  n                    # fetch the next line
  p                    # and print it
}
```

It is up to you how strict the condition has to be. I have chosen what seems like a sane selector to me; you can, of course, substitute any regex that reliably identifies the lines you want.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have modified the question. I also want to print xyz values only.

Comment: I've modified the answer to do that.